# Why selecting 2 numbers is different from rolling 2 dice simultaneously?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, dice

I have a maths exam tomorrow and this these questions are bugging me.

**Question 1: Two numbers are randomly selected from set of first 6 natural numbers, find probability that selected numbers are co-prime.**

Answer 1: Favorable cases are 11, but total cases are only 6C2, which is fine because if we pick 1,6 and 6,1, they are the same thing.

**Question 2: Two dices are thrown simultaneously, what is the probability that the the sum of number is 6**

Answer 2: Now, in this question why do we treat (2,4), and (4,2) as 2 different cases when in the above question we don’t?

I know this kind of sounds obvious but I a really confused about this, and would really appreciate some help

Comment: In the first question, it doesn't matter if you treat each sample as an ordered pair (so that $(2,4)\neq(4,2)$) or as an unordered pair (so that $\{2,4\}=\{4,2\}$). The resulting probability is the same because the question itself does not care about the ordering within each sample. Since each of these two approaches has pros and cons, you may pick whichever works better. Rather, the two questions together essentially address the [difference between sampling with and without replacement](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-sampling-with-and-without-replacement-python-7aff8f47ebe4).

Comment: In the first case you cannot get two $1$s, while in the second you can.  But in the second, this would be less likely than a $1$ or a $2$ in either order.  For a counting calculation you need probabilities of each thing being counted to be equal

Comment: I guess 1st question assumes different numbers in a pair, and this is the real difference between the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what your basic "event" is. In your case,

- for answer $1$, you chose "selection of two numbers out of six" as the base event, and by definition, that means order does not matter.
- For answer $2$, you chose "roll of two distinguishable dice" as the base event, and as such, the order matters.

Note that:

**For answer 1**, you could also take $(1,6)$ and $(6,1)$ as two different events. However, in that case, there are more than $11$ favorable cases. In fact, there are now $22$ favorable cases, and the probability you end up is the same, except you had to double count some things, overall complicating the solution. *Taking unordered sets was the least complicated method.*

**For answer 2**, you could also take unordered pairs as your base events. However, in that case, the events $\{1,1\}$ and $\{1,2\}$ would no longer have equal probability, so that would just complicate solving the final problem! *Taking ordered pairs was the least complicated method.*

Comment: For question 2, it is crystal clear, we roll 2 dice, we have 36 events, event (2,4) and event (4,2) are distinct events, they both ave a probability 1/36. For question 1, it is not so clear. "Two numbers are randomly selected from set of first 6 natural numbers" . Why (6,6) is exclude ?  If I select 1 number, and I repeat this, I select 2 numbers, and in some cases, they will be identical. What is the word which ensure that we select 2 distinct numbers ?

Comment: @Lourrran  The elements of a set are distinct, so if we select two numbers from a set, they must be different.

Comment: I think that 1st question is sloppy, and this is source of subsequent confusion.

Comment: Thanks N.F.  So SET is the important word in this context. But when I look in google translation to have this in my language, it is still confusing. 'Without replacement' or something similar would have been helpful here.  @Naman, (6,1) and (1,6) similar or not, it is not crucial in this case ; the question in mainly if (6,6) is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

You said that in 1st question number of total cases is $\binom62$. That means that only pairs of different numbers are considered (always good to remember that $\binom{n}{m}$ is number of $m$-element subsets in $n$-element set).

This is different from the 2nd question, where both dice can fall identically.

I think that the 1st question is sloppy, and you must guess what the question's author means by randomly selecting numbers.